# Which type should I use to match custom "HTTPError" class?

Tags: typescript

The following code (simplified for the purpose of writing this question) throws [TypeScript errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEASAq8AKBRATmg9m6BTAHgC64B2AJjOljgN4BQ00wmJEhaArsIdgBQC2uKGADmuAFzQ2aAJYkRASmj1GjCBwAOuNAKERRuBQ2gBfOmbpziaAGZhguOIiQB5DYRksYKvBmwBhcCgAfkkEZCpsczo6UEgYcKRlY21qQPiw50i0Y2ZWdi4eHUx3T1ZM5DcPLyUfRkIACxkIADpUgKCYAF5oEurWYLa-NHSoaGDe0q8htM7oCtRh4zMLOLH4IUJsvCJSCicI4eUzPLZoBsJCDQBJfLASB2geklwAdwOkXh92kc7JDbY2QANOYFEA) and I can’t figure out why.

FYI, I am trying to set `this.errorClass` to a class, not an instance of a class.

```js
class HTTPError extends Error {
  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message)
  }
}

interface HTTPOptions {
  errorClass?: HTTPError
}

class HTTP {
  errorClass: HTTPError
  constructor(options: HTTPOptions) {
    this.errorClass = options?.errorClass ? options.errorClass : HTTPError
  }
}

class TestError extends HTTPError {}
const httpInstance = new HTTP({
  errorClass: TestError,
})
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you provide a codepan?

Comment: @DoronG Thanks for helping out. I just added a link to a TypeScript playground to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Here's a [solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEASAq8AKBRATmg9m6BTAHgC64B2AJjOljgN4BQ00wmJEhaArsIdgBQC2uKGADmuAFzQ2aAJYkRASmj1GjCBwAOuNAKERRuBQ2gBfOmbpziaAGZhguOIiQB5DYRksYKvBmwBhcCgAfklCAE8tTBsnZCpsczo6UEgYBGRlY21qQNSwyNxo2NQ-NGNmVnYuHh1Md09WSXTXeq8lH0ZCAAsZCAA6bICgmABeaDqPL2CB0tyoaGDgxmb4ssYzCxT5+CFCVbwiUgpi-ZozCrZoLsJCDQBJSrASB2gxklwAd2LeH0G0OYgkh2bFWABpzEYgA):

```js
class HTTPError extends Error {
  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message)
  }
}

interface HTTPOptions {
  errorClass?: typeof HTTPError
}

class HTTP {
  errorClass: typeof HTTPError
  constructor(options: HTTPOptions) {
    this.errorClass = options?.errorClass ??  HTTPError
  }
}

class TestError extends HTTPError {}
const httpInstance = new HTTP({
  errorClass: TestError,
})
```

### The Details

The issue is that you're mixing up types and instances. You were trying to provide the class type of the error as a property, I assume, so you can do type matching and/or future instantiation, but you typed the property as an instance:

```js
errorClass?: HTTPError // takes an instance of HTTPError, e.g. new HTTPError(...) or undefined
```

instead of:

```js
errorClass?: typeof HTTPError // takes a class/factory/function which creates an instance of HTTPError, e.g. HTTPError, () => new HTTPError(), etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, Disclaimer: I don't do much TypeScript.

It seems like because of the declaration of errorClass being nullable, try this:

```
class HTTPError extends Error {
  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message)
  }
}

interface HTTPOptions {
  errorClass?: HTTPError
}

class HTTP {
  errorClass: HTTPError
  constructor(options: HTTPOptions) {
    this.errorClass = new HTTPError(options?.errorClass?.message || '')
  }
}

class TestError extends HTTPError {}
const httpInstance = new HTTP({
  errorClass: new TestError('test'),
})
```

This also works:

```
class HTTPError extends Error {
  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message)
  }
}

interface HTTPOptions {
  errorClass: HTTPError
}

class HTTP {
  errorClass: HTTPError
  constructor(options: HTTPOptions) {
    this.errorClass = options.errorClass || HTTPError
  }
}

class TestError extends HTTPError {}
const httpInstance = new HTTP({
  errorClass: new TestError(''),
})
```